# Passing Tuple2 Argument with -> versus ,

Tags: scala

Working on a [Functional Programming in Scala](http://www.manning.com/bjarnason/) exercise, I wrote out this function:

```
  def sequenceMap[K, V](ofa: Map[K,F[V]]): F[Map[K, V]] =
    ofa.foldLeft(unit(Map[K,V]()))((x, y) => map2(x, y._2)((a, b) => 
                                                           (a + (y._1 -> b))))
```

map2's signature:

`def map2[A,B,C](fa: F[A], fb: F[B])(f: (A,B) => C): F[C]`

However, when I replaced the last `->` with `,` to make the tuple2, the following compile-time `type mismatch` occurred:

```
[error]  found   : K
[error]  required: (K, V)
[error]     ofa.foldLeft(unit(Map[K,V]()))((x, y) => 
                                     map2(x, y._2)((a, b) => (a + (y._1 , b))))
```

Why is this occurring? Is it possible to use a comma and still avoid this compile-time problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you write `f(a, b)` you're applying the 2-ary function `f` to the 2 arguments `a` and `b`. To apply `f` to the `Tuple2` `(a, b)` you need to add another set of parens: `f((a, b))`.